# How do I do pattern matching against a Numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm a new Numpy user so I need some guidance.

Say I have this 3x3 matrix:

```
[[ -1,  1,  1],
 [ -1,  1,  1],
 [ -1, -1, -1]]
```

I want to detect a match with, for example, the following:

```
[[any,   1,   1],
 [any,   1,   1],
 [any, any, any]]
```

(In this case, the match will be `True`)

Is there a simple function / trick with Numpy to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53287262/matrix-match-in-python ?

Comment: @AndrewRyan Different. That question tries to find _exact_ match of a submatrix (different shape). My question is _inexact_ match of two same-shaped matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a mask and NaN:

```
a = np.array([[ -1,  1,  1],
              [ -1,  1,  1],
              [ -1, -1, -1]])

m = np.array([[np.nan,  1,  1],
              [np.nan,  1,  1],
              [np.nan, np.nan, -1]])

out = ((a == m) | np.isnan(m)).all()
# True
```